# Rails completes in 15 seconds, response received after 2 more minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, torquebox

I'm running into an unusual situation that I can't get to the bottom of.
We have a rails `4.1` application running on `jRuby 1.7.12` inside `Torquebox 3.1.0`. One of the API endpoints retrieves a list of objects.

Currently the database has just under 7000 records in. When an API request is made, these are queried and rendered in JSON using the `ActiveModel::Serializers`gem. This all works as we'd expect, and doing this in a rails console, it works perfectly.

The problem lies when making an actual API request. It seems to work as expected, and looking at the rails log, there is the output

```
Completed 200 OK in 6354ms (Views: 5479.0ms | ActiveRecord: 867.0ms)
```

At this point, I expect to see the data returned from the server, however it takes a good 2.7 minutes to actually see a response from the server. I've tried making the request from `Chrome`, `Safari` and even in `curl` just to make sure it's not a weird browser issue but not having any luck.

I've implemented some caching within the serialisers as described [here](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_6-fast_json_apis/). I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue however as it works as expected in a console, so I'm really confused.

What else could be going on that is causing the 2+ minute delay. During this time I'm seeing around a 100% CPU usage for Java, so something is definitely going on.

Comment: Is this in development or production? If you're using `bundler`, `bullet` should be under `development` group. Also, I'm not sure torquebox officially supports `jruby-1.7.12`. Their latest release mentions `1.7.11`.

Comment: Yeah this was in `development`, but it was still too high for `development`. You're right, it's not officially supported at the moment, but we've not come across any issues with it yet. `jruby-1.7.12` fixes a performance issue with something else though hence we're using it. On 1.7.11 we had a big performance issue in one area of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out it was the `bullet` gem taking up all the time. It seems that with that many records, detecting whether there is an N+1 query is quite time consuming. Simply disabling bullet reduces the time to exactly what the rails console says it is.